# Onomatopoetikon - spucken

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche ein deutsches Onomatopoetikon für (verächtliches) ausspucken.
Ähnlich wie:

[ptui! - expresses disgust; usually accompanied by spitting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226754/what-would-be-the-onomatopoeia-for-spit)

Comment: "Pah" und "pfui" (ja, dasselbe wie im Englischen) dürften die nächstliegenden sein. Laut Duden sind das sogar Wörter..

Comment: "Pah" hat Karl May in praktische allen seinen Romanen häufig verwendet. Heute ist es in der Literatur selten.

Comment: http://www.synonyme.de/pfui/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es gibt kein gängiges deutsches onomatopoetisches Wort für *verächtlich ausspucken*.

Etymologisch und lautlich am ähnlichsten ist das Wort

> pfui

<sup>(Das ist übrigens auch, soweit mir bekannt ist, das einzige Wort im Duden, das mit dem Diphthong [ʊɪ̯] auszusprechen ist.)</sup>

Aber, obwohl *pfui* vermutlich ganz genau aus einer lautlichen Nachahmung des Ausspuckens entstanden ist, assoziiert heute kaum noch kaum jemand diesen Vorgang mit dem Wort.

*»Pfui«* ist ein Wort, das Eltern zu Kinder sagen, wenn sie etwas unartiges oder schmutziges sagen, oder tun, oder wenn sie etwas schmutziges berühren

> **Pfui,** greif das nicht an, lass die Finger davon.
>   Ach, Julian, so etwas sagt man nicht, das ist **pfui.**

Auch beim Abrichten von Hunden habe ich dieses Wort schon gehört:

> **Pfui,** Hasso! **Pfui!** Nicht fressen! Aus! Lass das! Gehst du weg da! **Pfui** hab' ich gesagt!

Aber weder Eltern noch Kinder noch Hundebesitzer verbinden *spucken* mit dem Wort *pfui*. Es ist ein Ausdruck des Ekels.

Comment: Hundebesitzer erwarten nach einem "Pfui" selbstverständlich, dass der Hund, was immer er grade ins Maul genommen hat, wieder ausspuckt.

Comment: @tofro: Hast du schon mal einen Hund spucken sehen? Oder etwas *ausspucken*? Ich nicht. Es gibt nur sehr wenige Tierarten, die spucken können. Hunde gehören da nicht dazu.